# Returning a rapidjson::GenericValue from a function

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to make a function that returns a constructed rapidjson::Value from it. Like this:

```cpp
using JsonValue = rapidjson::GenericValue< rapidjson::UTF16LE<> >;
JsonValue MakeInt(int val)
{
  return JsonValue().SetInt(val); //copy-by-reference is forbidden
  //return JsonValue().SetInt(val).Move(); //same, Move() returns a reference
  //return std::move(JsonValue().SetInt(val)); //gcc complains about RVO failure
  //JsonValue json_val;
  //json_val.SetInt(val);
  //return json_val; //copy constructor is forbidden
}
```

However, each attempt fails due to various reasons listed in comments.

Obviously I could pass a destination value by reference:

```cpp
void WriteInt(JsonValue &dst_val, int val)
{
  dst_val.SetInt(val);
}
```

But I want to find how I'm expected to make it a return value.

PS I noticed there are a couple similarly spirited questions like this one [RapidJSON: Return GenericValue from Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837527/rapidjson-return-genericvalue-from-function) but none of them are answered.

UPDATE:
The actual solution is supposed to be just returning a value like this on any compiler that supports c++11:

```cpp
JsonValue MakeInt(int val)
{
  JsonValue json_val;
  json_val.SetInt(val);
  return json_val;
}
```

But this code failed to compile for us on clang build. Turns out the reason for that is not the compiler difference, but because the move constructor inside rapidjson.h is declared like this:

```cpp
#if RAPIDJSON_HAS_CXX11_RVALUE_REFS
    //! Move constructor in C++11
    GenericValue(GenericValue&& rhs) RAPIDJSON_NOEXCEPT : data_(rhs.data_) {
        rhs.data_.f.flags = kNullFlag; // give up contents
    }
#endif
```

and as it turns out the macro RAPIDJSON_HAS_CXX11_RVALUE_REFS was set to 0 due to its declaration in rapidjson.h:

```cpp
#if __has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references) && \
    (defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || defined(__GLIBCXX__) && __GLIBCXX__ >= 20080306)
#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_CXX11_RVALUE_REFS 1
#else
#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_CXX11_RVALUE_REFS 0
#endif
```

which is in turn because neither _LIBCPP_VERSION nor **GLIBCXX** are declared in our configuration. This is our build system bug on clang that somehow ended up not having its compiler macros defined.

Comment: If you can't get this working by returning a _rvalue reference_ (`JsonValue&& MakeInt(int val)`) then you could make it return `const JsonValue&` instead and inside your function do: `static thread_local JsonValue json_val; json_val.SetInt(val); return json_val;` -- or in the worst case, build a lightweight wrapper around `JsonValue` that encapsulates the move/copy semantics you want and return that.  Or just modify RapidJSON ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What compiler and C++ version are you using?
This compiles OK in MS Visual Studio 2019:

```
using JsonValue = rapidjson::GenericValue< rapidjson::UTF16LE<> >;
JsonValue MakeInt(int val)
{
    JsonValue json_val;
    json_val.SetInt(val);
    return json_val; 
}
```

I compile with C++11. Please see this (from document.h)

```
#if RAPIDJSON_HAS_CXX11_RVALUE_REFS
  //! Move constructor in C++11
  GenericValue(GenericValue&& rhs) RAPIDJSON_NOEXCEPT : data_(rhs.data_) {
      rhs.data_.f.flags = kNullFlag; // give up contents
  }
#endif
```

Comment: We're using the 3 major compilers on the buildbot: msvc, gcc, clang. Somehow each of these compilers compiles with some of my attempts (commented) and does not compile with others, but none of the variants compile with all of them. For example, this variant fails to compile on clang (it for some reason tries to construct a return object by reference instead of doing RVO).

Comment: Actually I went digging down this path and turns out the reason why it does not compile on clang is because we somehow have RAPIDJSON_HAS_CXX11_RVALUE_REFS set to 0 on that configuration, which is in turn because our _LIBCPP_VERSION (compiler-defined) is somehow not set. So I'd say it's a configuration problem rather than a code problem.